# MYSQL: JOIN two tables based on range on one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

**employee_salary**

```
   salary_id  emp_id  salary
    1         1       51000
    2         2       30000
    3         3       40000
    4         4       20000
    5         5       64000
    6         6       47000
    7         7       98000
```

**employee** tabe structure

```
emp_id |    first_name | last_name |    gender  | email | mobile  | dept_id  | is_active
```

Given salary slabs are

```
salary < 50000 as L
 70000 < salary > 50000 as M
salary > 70000 as H

According to salary slab list out the employee who fall in which salary slab
```

Comment: use a case statement?

Comment: unless an employee will have multiple salary rates, the salary_id column is redundant, just use emp_id as your primary key

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: deriving a "salary slab" isn't a matter of a JOIN operation, it's about an expression that derives the value of "salary slab" from existing columns, e.g. `CASE WHEN s.salary < 50000 THEN 'L' WHEN s.salary < 70000 THEN 'M' WHEN s.salary >= 70000 THEN 'H' ELSE NULL END AS salary_slab`

Comment: @WebChemist: not really. consider that the table might have historical salaries, raises, pay cuts, etc...

Comment: @MarcB which would imply multiple salary rates for the same user id, the exception I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving a "salary slab" isn't a matter of a JOIN operation, it's about an expression that derives the value of "salary slab" from existing columns.

The specification is bit incomplete, it doesn't specify the "salary slab" when the salary is exactly equal to 70000, or when salary is NULL.

As an example:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN s.salary <  50000 THEN 'L' 
         WHEN s.salary <  70000 THEN 'M'
         WHEN s.salary >= 70000 THEN 'H'
         ELSE NULL
       END AS salary_slab
     , e.emp_id
     , e.first_name
     , e.last_name
     , e.gender
     , e.email
     , e.mobile
     , e.dept_id
     , e.is_active
  FROM employee_salary s
  JOIN employee e
    ON e.emp_id = s.emp_id
 ORDER BY s.salary
```

The `CASE` expression in this example "completes" the specification, specifying that a salary equal to 70000 is in "salary slab" 'H', and NULL value for salary will return a "salary slab" value of NULL .

Note that the `ELSE NULL` could be omitted, since that's the default. Including it doesn't change the behavior, it just highlights the possibility that salary could be NULL. (This may not be an issue for your particular problem, if there's a NOT NULL constraint on the column. But extending this to a more general problem, for someone searching for an answer to the same question, it may be beneficial to include that.)

Comment: Why the condition as specified by @Marc did not worked for WHEN salary BETWEEN 50000 AND 70000 THEN 'M' which showed NULL but only taking Less than 70000 worked ?

Comment: @stackup: the CASE expression evaluates the WHEN conditions in order; what matters is the first WHEN condition that's found to evaluate to TRUE. So, in the second WHEN condition, it's not necessary to specify `AND salary >= 50000`, salary values less than 50000 were already "caught" by the first WHEN. For the example data, the expression in Marc B's answer should return the same values as the expression posted in my comment on your question, repeated here in my answer.

Comment: @stackup it is showing right might be you have interchanged the values, and both the condition will work even i you include the second condition as explained by spencer

Comment: @spencer7593 so many employee columns .. e.* would have worked :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, 
   CASE
      WHEN salary < 50000 THEN 'L'
      WHEN salary BETWEEN 50000 AND 70000 THEN 'M'
      ELSE  'H'
   END CASE AS slab
FROM employee_salary
```

Joining the employee table to get name/personal info is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: What if `salary` is `NULL`? And the specification for `'M'` was **`< 70000`**, not **`<= 70000`**.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about nulls, and obviously it'd be easy enough to add in another `when` clause to handle that.

Comment: @spencer7593, there could be many such `what if's` which are plain assumption. When answering, the simplest idea would be sticking to what been said in problem statement.

Comment: @Rahul: There aren't "many such what if's". There are exactly **two** values for which the specification is incomplete, **`70000`** and **`NULL`**. I value simplicity. But I also favor an explicitly complete specification; not glossing over it with "plain assumption".

Comment: @spencer7593, Agreed and my comment was in general and not specific to this question. No hard feelings. Cheers!